# floris.tools.power_rose.load() requires class instantiation

Tags: floris

I am writing a script to load a PowerRose object from a file I pickled previously using `floris.tools.power_rose.PowerRose.save()`. The script looks like this:

```
# General modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# FLORIS-specific modules
import floris.tools as wfct
import floris.tools.power_rose as pr

power_rose = pr.PowerRose(name, df_power, df_turbine_power_no_wake, df_turbine_power_baseline)
power_rose.load(filename = "PowerRose_All.p")
```

However, as is clear from the last two lines I have to instantiate the PowerRose class in order to load a PowerRose instance from a pickled PowerRose, which seems to me to be a causality problem. The only solution I can think of would be to create a DataFrames of the same size as "PowerRose_All.p" filled with zeros to use in the instatiation.

Comment: `load` isn't a class method, you need to call it on an *instance*.

Comment: Am I right in thinking I need to create a blank instance of the PowerRose class and then use the load method on that class then?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"a blank instance"*, but you certainly need to create an instance if you want to use instance methods.

Comment: Ok yes you're quite right. My issue is that the only way I can see to create an instance is to populate it with DataFrames, which can either be defined in the code or hopefully loaded from a pickled PowerRose object, which is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to instantiate a `power_rose` object before you can use the `load` method. However, you do not need to supply DataFrames to do this. This could be accomplished by:

```
import floris.tools.power_rose as pr

power_rose = pr.PowerRose()
power_rose.load(filename="PowerRose_All.p")
```